# Transforming data collected from form before persisting to entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony, orm

I am a newbie at Symfony2 and just hacking my way through some existing codebase. I need help in understanding how to achieve the following outcome.

I have a PriceList entity that stores:

```
DollarCostPrice, PercentDiscount1, PercentDiscount2, PercentCommission
```

I want the user to enter following 4 values through a form:

```
SalePrice, DollarDiscount1Price, DollarDiscount2Price, PercentCommission
```

where,

```
SalePrice = (DollarCostPrice + (PercentCommission * DollarCostPrice))

DollarDiscount1Price = ((DollarCostPrice + (PercentCommission * DollarCostPrice)) * (100 - PercentDiscount1)/100)

DollarDiscount2Price = ((DollarCostPrice + (PercentCommission * DollarCostPrice)) * (1 - PercentDiscount2)/100)
```

But once user has entered the above values, I will compute `DollarCostPrice, PercentDiscount1, PercentDiscount2, PercentCommission` that need to be persisted in the entity.

I want to use a collection of above 4 fields in a form so that users can enter this information for multiple items at once.

I am still new with using forms, collections and data-transformers in Symfony2. I would appreciate if someone could help me determine the best way to do it.

Comment: Start from [*How to Use Data Transformers*](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) this will answer your question

Comment: I actually went through that documentation before posting here. The example there is too simplistic and I am not able to comprehend how to bring together the concepts of a collection in forms and also apply the data transformation on multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way. Note I'm making assumptions here, you haven't provided any information on what entities relate to PriceList for example.

1. Create a PriceListType form type, you would have 1 mapped field (PercentCommission) and 3 non-mapped fields (SalePrice, DollarDiscount1Price, DollarDiscount2Price)

To add a non-mapped field:

> ->add('SalePrice', null, array('mapped' => false))

I'm assuming that PriceList has a relation to some sort of SKU object or similar. You need to consider how you manage this relation.

2. Start with a basic form for your PriceList Type. I'd use something similar to [this technique](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) for adding new PriceList items.

On Save I would initially just do the entity calculations in the controller to get things up and running quickly E.g.

```
    $yourForm->handleRequest($request);
    if ($yourForm->isValid()) {

        // loop through elements in your collection - note for non mapped fields
        // you need to access them like so: $form->get("DollarDiscount1Price")->getData();

        // calculate the data you wish to save to each PriceList entity, set and persist it

        $entityManager->persist($priceListEntity);

        // finish & finally flush
        $entityManager->flush();
    }
```

Then later I might move that functionality to a form event listener.

I don't see a need for a data transformer here myself as it'll add complexity. If you're planning to re-use this functionality in a number of forms maybe, but otherwise I don't think I'd worry about it.

People will tell you X is the ideal solution, but IMO start simple and refine as you go.